# Сброс значения элемента при достижении определенного значения

Tags: javascript

```
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

var next = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-next')[0];
var prev = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-prev')[0];

var slideIndex = 0;


var i = 0;
var slideRun  = setInterval(
    function(){
        slide[i++].classList = 'slide active';
        slide[i - 2].classList = 'slide';
    }
,1000);
```

Есть вот такой вот код, при достижении i значения slide.length, нужно чтобы он обнулялся.
пробовал вот такой вариант :

```
if(i == slide.length){
    i = 0;
}
```

но не работает.желательно нужно ещё и избавиться от error'ов в консоле.заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var slideRun  = setInterval(
  function() {
    slide[(i++) % slide.length].classList.add('active');
    slide[(i - 2 + slide.length) % slide.length].classList.remove('active');
  }
, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает как надо.Но возможно ли избавится от этого : file.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at file.js:23 ? это было и в моём коде тоже.

Comment: @AzizbekToshpolatov Да, я ужe исправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое  )^-^)

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё один вопрос, не отходя от темы? Это тот же код,Вы наверное уже поняли что работаю я над слайдером.И при настройке кнопок возникли проблемы :

```
 var slideNext = function(event){
    slide[(i++) % slide.length].classList.add('active');
    slide[(i - 2 + slide.length) % slide.length].classList.remove('active');

}

var slidePrev = function(event){
    slide[(i + 2 - slide.length) % slide.length].classList.remove('active');
}

next.addEventListener('click',slideNext);
prev.addEventListener('click',slidePrev);
 next работает отлично, а вот с prev возникли проблемы.да,  и ещё: можно ли стилизовать переход слайдера:скорость, плавность и т.д?
```

Comment: Задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос.

Comment: вот : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117768/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f